# Delegate a or buttons event to Backbone only

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I have html content like:

```
<button class="submit">Save</button>
```

and view like:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
 events: {
    'click .submit': 'save'
 },

 save: function() {}
}
```

When i'm clicking on this button, i see that backbone doens't handle this event, but instead standard browser actions are made (at least on Chrome). Same for `<a>` tag. I mean Backbone haven't bound to this tags.

Currently I've to use `<span>` for buttons, it works fine, but i'm wondering why I can't use  standard tags for buttons? How I can remove standard browser events, and use backbone for `<a>` or `<button>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The events are just 'listeners' - they are informed that the event happened. If you want to stop the event you must do

```
save: function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```

To check that Backbone handles the event, check that your listener (`save`) is invoked when you click. Backbone does not stop the default behavior, you have to do it yourself in you event handling function.

Another advice: put your buttons inside a `form` and add an event listener for `submit form`. This will work also if the user submits the form using the keyboard (the click event is only for the mouse).

Comment: I have `console.log('save')` at my save method - it never called for <button>/<a>. Only for <span>